# How do I loop through each account?

Tags: java

Specification
A bank account is created with an initial balance read in from the user. It offers a menu so the user can deposit and withdraw money, and see the balance. It also gets daily interest. The account menu choices are

d:deposit money: read in thea mount
w:withdraw money: read in the amount, and validate it
s:see the balance
x:exit anything 
else: help
A customer has three bank accounts,named credit, savings, and term; the annual interest rates are 0%, 1.2%, and 3.4%. The customer menu lets the user choose an account add interest, or see all balances. The menu choices are:
a:choose an account: enter the name
i: add interest to all accounts
s: show all accounts
x:exit
anything else: help
Add interest. Interest is added to a running total each day, and this total interest is added to the balance at the end of each month. The
bank adds the interest to an interest field everyday, and at the end of each month adds this amount to the balance and sets the interest
back to zero.
The menu choice adds daily interest to each account for 30 days, then adds the interest to the balance at the end of the month of 30 days.
The interest rate is expressed as an annual rate in percent, such as 3.4% per annum.
You have to convert it to a daily interest rate.
A normal year has 365 days. A leap year occurs every four years and has 366 days. The standard way to handle leap years is to use a year with 365.25 days.

Below is what I have so far; My question is how do I finish the string toString method() and choose method,

```
import java.util.*;

public class Customer
{   public static void main(String[] args)
    {   new Customer();  }


    public Customer()
    {
        setup();
    }

    private void setup()
    {
        accounts.add(new Account("",0.0));
        accounts.add(new Account("",0.0));
        accounts.add(new Account("",0.0));
    }

    public void use()
    {
        char choice;
        while((choice = readChoice()) != 'x')
        {
            switch(choice)
            {
                case 'a': choose(); break;
                case 'i': addInterest(); break;
                case 's': show(); break;
                default: help();
            }
        }   
    }

    private char readChoice()
    {   return 'x'; }


    private void choose()
    {
        // ask for acount
        // search for that ;particular accounts using account(name)

        // use the newly found account (given that it is found)
    }

    private String readName()
    {
        //gives accountName you are searching for
        System.out.print("??? account ???; ");
        return In.nextLine();

    }

    private Account account(String name)
    {   return null;    }

    private void addInterest()
    {   for (Account account: accounts)
        {   for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
                account.addDailyInterest();
            account.addMonthlyInterest();   }}

    private void help()
    {   String s = "The menu choices are";
        s += "\n  a: choose an account";
        s += "\n  i: add interest to all accounts";
        s += "\n  s show";
        s += "\n  x exit";
        System.out.println(s);   }

    private void show()
    {
        System.out.println(this);
    }

    public String toString()
    {   String s = "";
        // loop through each account
        // add each account toString();
        // seperate each account object using a new line.
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is strange ... you already know how to iterate over your arrays and you how to append strings with a line separator. What your real issue here?

Comment: DId you even read my question? How do I finish the choose and toString method()?

Comment: Yes I've read it and I still don't know  why you're unable to implement the `toString()` method by yourself. The `choose()` might be a bit different here, but haven't you tried something first?

Answer (score 0):

well, does it compile at all? Normally I would go with the Customer class having a `private List<Account> accountList` which would be easy to extended (i see the `accounts.add(new Account("",0.0));` but no List declaration)

Then overwrite `toSting` method in Account so that it will print what suits You best. Finally in the Customer just iterate over the accountList like:

```
public String toString()
{   String s = "";
    for (Account account:accountList){
        s += account.toString() + "\n";
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: yes I have this in my customer class. private LinkedList<Accounts> account = new LinkedList<Accounts>();

Comment: so just simply overwrite `toString` in Account class and use the posted code. Also considering the `choose` method, it would be in similar manner, loop over whole accountList and if any account matches Your name just return it.